# Using getElementById to Change html content

Tags: javascript, html, forms, if-statement

Okay, so I recently started learning html/css and js. In multiple tutorials I cannot figure out how to properly use the getElementById function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="first">My Practice Page!</h1>

    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()"
    <label>Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
        var nm = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (nm == "Don") {
            document.write("Hi, Don");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            document.write("Hi, stranger.");
            return false;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The submit button works and registers that fname equals the input text, but it either does not assign that value to nm or I'm not using document.write correctly.

Anyone have any ideas? This seems like it will be a stupid little thing.

Comment: You can not have a `return` outside of a `function`. You also have invalid html. Your form tag needs a `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your `<form>` element doesn't have the `>` symbol at the end of the opening tag.

Next, your script runs as soon as the page is loaded and, at that time, the user hasn't had a chance to enter anything into the field.

Next, `document.write` shouldn't be used in this situation as it will overwrite an existing document. Instead, set up an empty element that you will write your output to.

Also, since you aren't actually submitting form data anywhere, don't use a submit button and the `submit` event. Just use a regular button and its `click` event.

And, don't use inline HTML event attributes (`onsubmit`). Instead, set up your event handlers in JavaScript.

Lastly, you haven't given any element an `id`, so you can't use `.getElementById()` to find any.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="first">My Practice Page!</h1>

    <form name="myForm">
      <label>Name:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
      <!-- Use a regular button since you aren't submitting form data anywhere -->
      <input type="button" value="Submit">
    </form>
    
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script>
      // Set up a click event handler for the button
      document.querySelector("[type='button']").addEventListener("click", validateForm);
      
      // Get the reference to your text field. You can't get it by its id unless you've
      // given it an id. name is not the same thing as id.
      var fName = document.getElementById("fname");
      
      // You didn't have your code inside of the callback function
      function validateForm(){

        if (fName.value == "Don") {
            // Just populate a pre-existing element with the correct data.
            output.textContent = "Hi, Don";
        }
        else {
            output.textContent = "Hi, stranger.";
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you forgot declare function validateform

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="first">My Practice Page!</h1>

    <form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <label>Name:</label><br />
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script>
    function validateForm(){
        var nm = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if (nm == "Don") {
            document.write("Hi, Don");
            return true;
        }
        else {
            document.write("Hi, stranger.");
            return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And <form misses its >.

Answer (score 0):

That is because JS does not magically execute the logic: what you need to do is to listen to the form submission event instead (avoid using inline JS binding):

```
document.forms["myForm"].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    // Prevents default form submission
    e.preventDefault();

    // Your logic here
});
```

```js
document.forms["myForm"].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var nm = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (nm.value === "Don") {
    output.textContent = "Hi, Don";
  } else {
    output.textContent = "Hi, stranger.";
  }
});
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <label>Name:</label><br />
  <input type="text" name="fname" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<p id="output"></p>
```

If you then choose to submit the form programmatically within the if/else block, you can simply call `document.forms["myForm"].submit()` directly.

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` on strings that don't contain any HTML. Use `.textContent` instead. And, if you're not actually submitting data anywhere, don't use the `submit` event and a submit button.